# Extra step during Windows boot?

Tags: windows-10, boot

I broke my Windows 10's ability to boot while trying to install a dual boot with Linux. I fixed it by a somewhat complicated procedure. It boots…but always displays the screen below along the way, which it never used to do.

Questions:

1. How can I get rid of this step and have it boot directly into Windows?
2. Can I make this step optional by holding down a particular key, so that I COULD choose a different boot partition? (I might use this to try and revive the dual boot into Linux, but driven by the Windows boot manager.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may remove and extra entry in the boot menu this way:

- Open an elevated command prompt
- Run the following command : `bcdedit`
- Find the *identifier* line for the entry you want to delete. The currently loaded Windows has the *{current} identifier* so is not to be touched.
  The entry in question should be named "Windows Recovery Environment".
- Run the command `bcdedit /delete {identifier}`.

If you're not sure, take a screenshot of the results of the `bcdedit`
command and include it in your post.